# how to create a jdbc connection using application user in Oracle RAS (Oracle 12c)

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, oracle-ras

I am trying to implement a POC using Oracle Real Application Security (RAS) in Oracle 12C.

I have done the RAS setup with HR demo on Oracle side, which is working fine (I verified it using SQLDeveloper & SQLPlus).

now I am trying to establish a java jdbc connection using "Application User" (dispatcher) as mentioned in below link:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBFSG/midtierjava.htm#DBFSG99936

But I am getting below error:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Though connection using "Database User" is working fine.

How to set a JDBC connection using "Application User" (not "Database User") ?

Answer (score 0):

To use RAS you still need to connect to the Database using the regular Database user through the JDBC driver. Once you have a JDBC connection you can start using the Security Manager `oracle.security.xs.XSSecurityManager` and you call `getSession` using the Application User.

Comment: i did the same, here is my code:

public static void setupConnection() throws Exception
{
// getting the connection from database user. This connection is successsful
mgrConnection = DriverManager.getConnection( <database_url>,<database_user>,<database_password>);
mgr = XSSessionManager.getSessionManager( mgrConnection, 30, 2048000 );
// getting the connection from application user (dispatcher). This connection is throwing Invalid Username/Password exception
appConnection = DriverManager.getConnection( <database_url>,<dispatcher_application_user>,<dispatcher_application_password>);
}